# Wedge to make half of a circle with variable height and width

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to put half of a circle in a plot (matplotlib) but instead I end up with a line because my y axis max is 10,000 and my x axis max is 5.

I was wondering if it was possible to set the width to 2.5 and the height to 5,000 for the wedge function?

```
def circleplot():
    # preparer le graph
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_xlim(xmin=0, xmax=5)
    ax.set_ylim(ymin=0, ymax=10000)

    w1 = Wedge((2.5, 5000), 2.5, 0, 180, width=0.1, color='black')
    ax.add_patch(w1)
    plt.show()

circleplot()
```

Comment: `Wedge` draws a circle or part of a circle, not an ellipse.  It wouldn't be hard to generate the points you need as a line plot.

Comment: @TimRoberts The y axis might change, so how could I plot an half circle (in that case a variable ellipse height) with a line plot?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html#plotting-in-physical-coordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I mean.  Just create the points as a circle using normal trigonometry.  As long as you apply two different scale for x and y, you can make it look normal.  I use 180 points along the half-circle, and it looks pretty smooth.  You could probably get by with even fewer than that.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def circleplot():
# preparer le graph
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_xlim(xmin=0, xmax=5)
    ax.set_ylim(ymin=0, ymax=10000)

    ctr = (2.5, 5000)
    scl = (2.5, 5000)
    xx = []
    yy = []
    for angle in range(180):
        x = ctr[0] + scl[0] * math.cos(angle * math.pi / 180)
        y = ctr[1] + scl[1] * math.sin(angle * math.pi / 180)
        xx.append(x)
        yy.append(y)
    xx.append(xx[0])
    yy.append(yy[0])

    ax.plot(xx,yy)

circleplot()
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]